# Shiny reconnecting to existing session

Tags: r, server, shiny

I created a Shiny app which is doing a long computation and therefore i am running it on a local server in my Network.

I can access the app via my computer, upload files and start the calculation. But when I close the browser and access the app via a weblink again, Shiny will start a new empty session.

How can I reconnect to the "closed" session with the hopefully still running computation and uploaded files?

It seems that it may be possible with RStudio Connect or running the app via a ShinyServer. Is there another easy way to handle it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reconnecting to the exact same session seems not possible. I found after a lot of research the Bookmark function, which saves your Input inside a new URL or on a Server. See references here: [Link](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/bookmarking-state.html)

Unfortunately, it didnt work really good because i had bigger plots and tables as saved output.

I solved the problem with a workaround. In the end of the computation i save the whole environment with `save.image(file='myEnvironment.RData')`

I added an actionbutton and by clicking it loads the saved environment with `load('myEnvironment.RData')`. After this, all files are back in the environment and new outputs can be created by e.g. `output$xy <- renderPlot({XY})`.

Hope that helps